# How to avoid duplicate row where one column value will get first table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. And I want to avoid duplicate values where one column value will get from any table.
table `a`

| id | value | name | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | a | 27 |
| 2 | 56 | b | 23 |
| 3 | 57 | c | 22 |

table `b`

| id | value | name | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | a | 29 |
| 5 | 58 | d | 23 |
| 6 | 59 | e | 22 |

expected result

| id | value | name | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | a | 27 |
| 2 | 56 | b | 23 |
| 3 | 57 | c | 22 |
| 5 | 58 | d | 23 |
| 6 | 59 | e | 22 |

here

| id | value | name | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | a | 29 |

the row will be removed.

Comment: Why? Why isn't (1, 55, a, 27) removed? What does this: "avoid duplicate values where one column value will get from any table" mean? Which column is "one column"?

Comment: I, too, don't understand what rule you want to apply here. Do you remove the row because its `id` exists in table `a` and `a` has precedence over `b`? Or because its `value` exists in table `a` and `a` has precedence over `b`? Or because its `name` exists in table `a` and the row with the lesser pid wins? Or any combination of the above? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to concatenate the two tables with an additional priority column and then use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to find each row with the highest priority:

```sql
SELECT id,
       value,
       name,
       pid
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         name,
         pid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, value, name ORDER BY priority) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT id, value, name, pid, 1 AS priority FROM a UNION ALL
    SELECT id, value, name, pid, 2 AS priority FROM b
  )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (id, name, value, pid) AS
SELECT 1, 'a', 55, 27 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b', 56, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'c', 57, 22 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b (id, name, value, pid) AS
SELECT 1, 'a', 55, 29 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'd', 58, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'e', 59, 22 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | VALUE | NAME | PID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | a | 27 |
| 2 | 56 | b | 23 |
| 3 | 57 | c | 22 |
| 5 | 58 | d | 23 |
| 6 | 59 | e | 22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gORbCzE4)